# Which is faster: Multiple small RPMs or Single Structure RPM

Tags: winapi

In C++, I am using ReadProcessMemory to obtain the values of some numbers. Each of the numbers is in tandem, and there are five different numbers. Is it faster to do five, single RPM calls to read each number individually, or is it faster do a single RPM call that reads an entire structure built to contain these five numbers? For instance,

```
Mem.Read<int>(DWORD64 L1);
Mem.Read<int>(DWORD64 L1);
Mem.Read<int>(DWORD64 L1);
Mem.Read<int>(DWORD64 L1);
Mem.Read<int>(DWORD64 L1);
```

or

```
struct numbers{
   int a;
   int b;
   int c;
   int d;
   int e;
  };
Mem.Read<numbers>(DWORD64 L1)
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you need to pick up 5 packs of milk at the store, would it be faster to run down there 5 times and carry one home each, or pick up all 5 and travel only once? If you have to ask, you probably should not be calling `ReadProcessMemory` to begin with.

Comment: strange question. of course in this case single call to `ReadProcessMemory` will be in 5 time faster than 5 calls

Comment: The question was poorly phrased. I meant to say, is it better to do a very large read of a structure, or individual RPM calls? For instance, what if my structure was several thousands bits in size....

Comment: Timers. Ever heard of them? Use one and do your own testing. Be aware that Windows preemptively multi-tasks, so in order to get reasonably accurate figures, you'll need to perform a loop in which you perform each task many times to get an average. E.g 1000 or 10,000 times execute 5 reads, then divide the total time by the loop count. Next, do the same thing with the 1 larger read- executing it many thousands of times in a loop before dividing the total time. There's oodles and oodles of information avail- I intend only to give a brief overview of the process. Do your own research and timing..

Comment: If you need to read *"several thousands bits"* (which doesn't qualify as *"very large"*), you need to read several thousand bits. Doing it in one system call is faster than doing thousands of calls to read a single byte each.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ReadProcessMemory` to read memory is "slow" so one large operation is going to be faster than many small reads.

If we ignore the fact that `ReadProcessMemory` is probably a system call that has to perform a context switch to kernel mode and access the pages of a different process (that might be paged out etc.) you can still make assumptions about the speed of one large vs many small reads.

Imagine you are reading from your own process. Many calls to `memcpy` with a small buffer is slower than one large copy operation. Just calling a function has some overhead; a call instruction, setting up the stack, doing the actual work and then restoring the stack and returning. A typical `memcpy` implementation is often optimized for larger reads and will do a little extra work upfront to make the source address aligned so it can read the majority of the memory in 4 or 8 byte chunks (maybe even larger on newer CPUs).

I would normally say that you need to measure with a timer if you are not sure about performance but in this case it is a no-brainer, just do the single read.